# slicing numpy array in periodic conditions

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

how can I slice a 3x3 shape numpy array in periodic conditions.

for example, for simplicity its in one dimension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(10))
```

if the slice is within the length of the array it is straightforward

```
sub = a[2:8]
```

the result is `array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`. Now if I need to slice from 7 to 5 ...

```
sub = a[7:5]
```

the result is obviously `array([], dtype=int32)`. But what I need is `array([7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4])`

Is there any efficient way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likewise a good and easy way of doing a rolled or slicing or slicing in periodic conditions is by using the modulo and the numpy.reshape.
for example

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3,3,3))
array([[[ 0.98869832,  0.56508155,  0.05431135],
        [ 0.59721238,  0.62269635,  0.78196073],
        [ 0.03046364,  0.25689747,  0.85072087]],

       [[ 0.63096169,  0.66061845,  0.88362948],
        [ 0.66854665,  0.02621923,  0.41399149],
        [ 0.72104873,  0.45633403,  0.81190428]],

       [[ 0.42368236,  0.11258298,  0.27987449],
        [ 0.65115635,  0.42433058,  0.051015  ],
        [ 0.60465148,  0.12601221,  0.46014229]]])
```

lets say we need to slice [0:3, -1:1, 0:3] where 3:1 is a rolled slice.

```
a[0:3, -1:1, 0:3]
array([], shape=(3, 0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

This is very normal. the solution is:

```
sl0 = np.array(range(0,3)).reshape(-1,1, 1)%a.shape[0]
sl1 = np.array(range(-1,1)).reshape(1,-1, 1)%a.shape[1]
sl2 = np.array(range(0,3)).reshape(1,1,-1)%a.shape[2]

a[sl0,sl1,sl2]
array([[[ 0.03046364,  0.25689747,  0.85072087],
        [ 0.98869832,  0.56508155,  0.05431135]],

       [[ 0.72104873,  0.45633403,  0.81190428],
        [ 0.63096169,  0.66061845,  0.88362948]],

       [[ 0.60465148,  0.12601221,  0.46014229],
        [ 0.42368236,  0.11258298,  0.27987449]]])
```

Comment: Don't quite see the advantage over roll (this is basically what it does afterall). Currently you could probably slightly beat both speed wise with a concatenate call probably. Edit: Ah sorry, you wanted not necessarily the whole axes, so of course there is a difference, just not in the example.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [numpy.roll](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).  From the examples:

```
x = np.arange(10)

np.roll(x, 2)
array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

np.roll(x, -2)
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

Comment: numpy.roll is one solution but for big arrays in a for loop it becomes heavy I am looking for straightforward slicing.

Comment: Why do you think slicing would be any faster (even if it were possible)?

Comment: because slicing in worst cases will copy the sliced part or the array whereas numpy.roll will always copy the whole array. and this is not ideal in my case

Comment: Why do you think roll does as a copy as a opposed to a view?

Comment: because it does :) try it and you will see

Comment: @Cobry Thats just wrong, slicing never copies, and this is simply not possible without a copy (unless you add new dimensions).

Comment: Anyway, sorry if that seemed harsh, but you can use `take` or a fancy index to do get the part as a copy. Slicing creates views, and views cannot generally represent such an operation.

Comment: @seberg Elaborate on the "unless you add new dimensions" please!

Comment: @Jaime didn't think, that did not make much sense either... I thought you could do the wrap-around along a second dimension, but then the chunks need to be the same size, etc.