# slicing-numpy-array-in-periodic-conditions with numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a code that adds a kernel in fframe by using periodic boundary conditions on the fframe.

I implemented periodic boundary conditions according to this post
[slicing numpy array in periodic conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113181/slicing-numpy-array-in-periodic-conditions).

It works with numba with the @jit wrapper but I don't get any speed up.
When I add the @njit

I got this error.

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function setitem>) with argument(s) of 
type(s): (array(int64, 2d, C), tuple(array(int64, 2d, C) x 2), array(int32,2d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:

All templates rejected with literals.
```

How can I work around with this index slicing for periodic boundary conditions in numba?

"""

```
kernell = np.random.randint(0,10,(25,25))
fframe = np.random.randint(0,2,(77,77))

@njit
def init_test(frame, kernel, nn):
    dimXsp, dimYsp = kernel.shape
    dimXfr, dimYfr =frame.shape

    Xcoord = np.random.randint(0,dimXfr,nn)
    Ycoord = np.random.randint(0,dimYfr,nn)

    black = frame * 0

    for ff in prange(nn):
        sl0 = np.arange(Xcoord[ff]-dimXsp//2,Xcoord[ff]+dimXsp//2+1).reshape(-1,1)% dimXfr
        sl1 = np.arange(Ycoord[ff]-dimYsp//2,Ycoord[ff]+dimYsp//2+1).reshape(1,-1)% dimYfr

        black[sl0,sl1] = kernel

    return Xcoord, Ycoord, black
```

"""

Thanks :)

Comment: *"It works fine as long as I don't add the @njit"* - would you mind telling us what error you got?

Comment: Sorry I added the error.

Comment: Can you try with `@jit` instead of `@njit`?  It may not be as fast as njit would be, but I bet it works.

Comment: It works with jit instead of njit but I don't see any speed up.

Comment: maybe the user https://stackoverflow.com/users/1508904/cobry could help?

Comment: Another potential issue is making sure you're using consistent array types. Check that kernel has the same type as black[I,j]?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that randint only accepts 2 arguments in numba:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: Actually not. If I delete the last line the code runs. The issue is with the slicing. The numba version that I am using is 0.43.1

Comment: Could you please explain this more? Should I use numpy random?